# How to parse the json when having same response but different mapping

Tags: retrofit

I am trying to use Retrofit to send requests and be able to use the response.

The service returns a json like this

```
  {
     "code" : 0,
     "msg"  : "User received",
     "data" : {
         "name" : "x",
         "tags" : [ "a", "b", "c" ]
     }
   }
```

Where the structure (code, msg and data) is the same but what goes inside the data will differ.  In this example should be mapped to a User class.    For other calls it would return the list of posts and so on.  And if there is an error there will be no data component, but instead an errors property.

I though I could have a specific subclass of a Response type and hint Retrofit to use it.

```
public class Response {
  int code;
  String msg;
}

public class UserResponse extends Response {
  User data;
}
```

But when I don't have the data element in the return the program simply breaks when executes the action.

Comment: There isn't anything particularly wrong with what you are trying to do. Could you post a log with the exception you are getting? What are you using to parse de JSON response? ¿Gson? ¿Jackson?

Comment: I started the code from scratch and it worked.  Provably something wrong with the way was using.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your com.retrofit.converter.Convert, if the code and msg properties are used for debugging ;)
For example, I use Gson to convert json to java type. I will get the sub JsonElement "data" as gson parameter in fromBody method (public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) throws ConversionException).

```
return gson.fromJson(theDataJsonElement, type);
```

And of course, don't forget to set the converter to your adapter

```
restAdapter.setConverter(new YourImplementedConverter());
```